# Dragging a formula down without skipping numbers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Below, in the screenshot, is a sheet im using to collect movie reviews amongst 20 people. I created 20 sheets, one for each person, that i will then make private for each person. I want to pull those ratings from each sheet, into this master sheet(pictured) to bring them all together.

I have created this range for a single movie and am trying to copy this template )From row one down to thee "Final rating" row) down 60 times. I am able to draw in the ratings and reviews from each sheet to bring in for one movie. When i attempt to drag this down, the reference cell numbers skip more than i would like.

For an example:

**Currently when i try to drag down this template ive made, i see in column D (my screenshot is me attempting to copy down the template.):**

Muha!C2
JoshB!C2
Davis!C2
....
Final rating...

Muha!C24
JoshB!C24
Davis!C24
....
Final rating...

**I want to be able to drag down this template so i see,**

Muha!C2
JoshB!C2
Davis!C2
....
Final rating...

Muha!C3
JoshB!C3
Davis!C3
....
Final rating...

Let me know if i need to explain this better :) Im not too good with eexcel/GS and dont want to have to manually type in the numbers for hundreds of rows.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the values in your Legend column EXACTLY matched the sheet names for those folks (eg "Josh B." would instead be written "JoshB") then you could use: `=INDIRECT(B2 & "!" & "C2")`. You could copy that down for all reviewers and the review `C2` reference will remain consistent since it's just text, while the reviewer reference `B2` updates with each row. Then for Movie 2 you'd just update it `=INDIRECT(B2 & "!" & "C3")` and do the same. And so on for Movie 3, etc.